# Login form doesn't verify the password

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I am working on a login form and the password doesn't get verified from some reason. The user supposed to log in into system with email and password. I am matching user based on the email with the data in database. Could you please look at it?

[Customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pww3z.jpg)

HTML form in file index.php

```html
                  

<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 align-center">
   <img src="images/logo-white.png" alt="" height="120px" width="120px" />
   <h5 class="font-alt">Login to Your Account</h5>
   <br/>
   <form method="post" action="login.php" class="form">
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-md form-control" placeholder="Email" required />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-md form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <input type="submit" name="login" class="login btn btn-mod btn-medium" id="btnLogIn" value="Login" />
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

File login.php

```
 <?php
require_once 'connection_db.php';
$response = new stdClass;
if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $response->success = false;
    $response->message = 'Email and password cannot be empty.';
} else {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `email` = ? ';

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    // print_r($password, true);

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $array = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        // print_r($array, true);
        if (count($array)) {
            $response->success = true;
            $response->message = 'Login successful.';
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['current_page'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            header("Location: ". $_SESSION['current_page']);

        } else {
            $response->success = false;
            $response->message = 'Wrong username or password.';
            header("Location: index.php#test-popup");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $response->success = false;
        $response->message = "Error.";
    }
}
// unset($db);
?>
```

Comment: So where do you compare password from db with password from input?

Comment: You need to password_verify within the login script, not password_hash

Comment: First of all, I suggest you to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php. What does the $array outputs?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic setup of how your login script should look:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!empty($email) && !empty($password))
    {
        $res = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `email` = ?");
        $res->execute([$email]);

        $row = $res->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if ($res->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            if (password_verify($password, $row['password']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['uid'];

                header('Location: loggedIn.php');
            } else {
                // echo incorrect pass
            }
        } else {
            // echo no such user...
        }
    } else {
        // echo something...
    }
}
```

You should be using `password_verify` for your login script. You only use `password_hash` for registering to hash the password that has been submitted.

Comment: If I am using MySQLi accross whole application, should I use `$array = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` instead of `$row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` ?   @Option

Comment: That would work yes, sorry. I'll edit my side for you now.

Comment: It's redirecting me to login.php, which is set as action in my HTML form `<form method="post" action="login.php" class="form">` in both cases with WRONG/RIGHT credentials

Comment: Where are you putting the php? Within the same file as the html or within login.php?

Comment: Within login.php

Comment: So the way I'd do this is remove login.php from the form and place the php above the form within 1 file. No need to pass it elsewhere.

Comment: I am using log in in more than just one page.So it would be better to keep it in separate folder. Anyway, I tried it just to see what it does, and says I have inputted worng credentials even thus I didn't